# Lua on eclipse, No suggested completion

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, lua, koneki

I've set Lua koneki on my eclipse, it recognize lua files and I can start a Lua project, however, once I'm typing, eclipse doesn't suggest any completion to what I write.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

That suggestion might look stupid but if you come from another IDE, maybe you simply didn't hit CTRL+SPACE to trigger autocompletion?